# Database storage vs Cookies - To store form data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, cookies

Good day to all,

I have a form with around 90 to 100 fields, divided into sub forms, which are loaded using ajax each time a form has to be displayed. but i would like to retain the data on the form fields every time a subform is loaded(lets say on an accidental page refresh or even if the user is switching between sub forms). What is the best way that this can be done.

I was thinking that i can store it in cookies or lets say in the database. But, storing it in the database would mean that i would have to query for the fields data every time a sub form is loaded. And again, if it was cookies, it has to read the data stored in the cookie files. I need some help with deciding what is the most efficient way, more in terms of speed.

What is the best way among these, or is there any other possibility to retain the fields data in the sub forms, every time they are loaded (which are loaded via AJAX each time.)

I am working with PHP and Codeigniter framework.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do it in client side. Sisyphus is a good tool for it which uses local storage.

Comment: i wish i could accept both answers from Tim and Marshall, both are great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first simplify it by using serialize:

```
$data = serialize(array_merge($_POST,$olddata));
```

Then that may be enough for you, but it's now super easy to store it anywhere since it is just a string. To reform it into its original state:

```
$data = unserialize($data);
```

.. wherever you end up pulling it from - database,session,etc..

Answer (score 3):

A form like that needs to be durably stored. I would consider session state to smooth out the sub form loads, with writes to the database whenever the user updates something of consequence. Personally, I would start with a database-only solution, and then add session state if performance is an issue.

Cookies aren't meant to store large amounts of data. Even if it *were* possible, they bloat the request considerably (imagine 100 form fields all being transmitted with every request).

Local storage in the browser is also an option, though I would consider other options first.

Comment: Yes, i had the same feeling about cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Prose of database
It can also access from other computer too 
You can store far far more data then cookie
Cones 
If you retrive data by ajax it coukd cose more load on server

Cookie
Faster than database no query , fetch and all process .
Cones
Limited amount of space

However you can use local storage

So answer is database storage